# Split serial number of an array

Tags: php, arrays, split

I have the following array of numbers ($data) and i want to split this into two arrays (range1 and 2).

I just will not advance as you can see. Can someone give me a tip how I can fix this?

```
$data = array( 16,17,18,19,20,23,24,25,26 );

$range1 = array();
$range2 = array();

$firstday = reset( $data );
$lastday = end( $data );

for($x = $firstday;$x <= $lastday; $x++ ){
    if( $firstday == $x ){
        $range1 =.$x;    
    }
    elseif( $x - $firstday == 1){
        $range2 =.$x;
    }
}

Output must be array(16,17,18,19,20); array(23,24,25,26);
```

Comment: Check here http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php. Also, this doesn't look right `$range1 =. $x`. Do you mean `$range []= $x`?

Comment: on what condition do you need to split them ?

Comment: I am trying to make a calendar and the days in the $data array are the occupied data. So these are 2 periods and i want to make 2 arrays.

Answer (score 3):

```
    $data = array( 16,17,18,19,20,23,24,25,26);
    $output1 = array_slice($data, 0, 5); 
    $output2 = array_slice($data, 5, 4);
```

Comment: Yes thats it! But how can i trace the number 5 and 4?

Comment: Take a tour of the PHP manual, see here http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php

Comment: Here 2nd parameter is the offset & 3rd parameter is length & Just see http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php also told by @elclanrs

Answer (score 0):

The same way used by @Jenson M John,

getting half of the array

```
$count = count($data);
$output1 = array_slice($data, 0, ceil($count/2)); 
$output2 = array_slice($data, ceil($count/2), $count-(ceil($count/2)));
```

Comment: Sorry i was to fast. This works if you have 2 periods. But if the array is array(1,2,3,5,6,7,25,26,28);?

Comment: @Bas what is your expected output for the above array ?

Comment: Sorry this array(1,2,3,5,6,7,25,26,28); must be array(1,2,3,5,6,7,25,26,27,28); $output1 = array(1,2,3); $output2 = array(5,6,7); $output3 = array(25,26,27,28);

Comment: @Bas You should mention this in your question. why output3 having 4 values and where define 3 values per array ?

Comment: I retrieve this example array from dbase array(1,2,3,5,6,7,25,26,27,28); These are the occupied data. I want to split it in this example in 3 arrays but its also possible to retrieve this like array(15,16,17,25,26,27,28); This has to be 2 arrays